# How to turn "cnv.print" command from "cnv-seq" package to an object?

Tags: r, printing, data.table

This command:

```
cnv.print(data)
```

prints exactly the table that I need and that has this function in cnv-seq package:

```
cnv.print <- function(cnv, file="")
{
    cat('cnv', 'chromosome', 'start', 'end', 'size', 'log2', 'p.value', sep="\t", file=file,fill=TRUE, append=TRUE)
    for(i in seq(max(min(cnv$cnv),1), max(cnv$cnv)))
    {
        sub <- subset(cnv, cnv==i)
        start <- ceiling(mean(c(min(sub$start), min(sub$position))))
        end <- floor(mean(c(max(sub$end), max(sub$position))))
        cat(paste('CNVR_',i,sep=''), paste('chr', unique(sub$chromosome), sep=''), start, end, end-start+1, unique(sub$cnv.log2), unique(sub$cnv.p.value), sep="\t", file=file, fill=TRUE, append=TRUE)
    }
}
```

This is the head of the print:

```
> cnv<- as.data.table (cnv.print(data))
cnv     chromosome      start   end     size    log2    p.value
CNVR_1  chrchr14        192633  200377  7745    3.08669 2.852405e-295
CNVR_2  chrchr14        1665929 1673673 7745    1.953198        4.948368e-197
CNVR_3  chrchr14        2587465 2595209 7745    1.10941 1.772911e-89
CNVR_4  chrchr14        5177833 5185577 7745    Inf     NA
CNVR_5  chrchr14        8143785 8151529 7745    0.8412138       3.239654e-56
CNVR_6  chrchr14        9779705 9787449 7745    2.501727        2.677463e-252
...
```

The problem is that I cannot transform this "print" to an object to export as a final spreadsheet.
I tried this:

```
cnv<- cnv.print(data)
library(data.table)    
cnv<- as.data.table (cnv.print(data))
```

these commands only prints the table again and cnv object description is:

```
Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols)
```

Comment: Function `sink` might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `cnv.print` can directly print to files.

```
cnv.print(data, file="mydata.txt")
# the output of cnv.print to the file mydata.txt is well formatted
# if you want to further process this file in R, you can read it into R

data <- fread("mydata.txt", header=T, sep="\t")
```

Comment: thank you but still breaking lines. Should have some additional command to avoid this. Like in the command line when you include -w to avoid to break lines on scripts

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Pascal, yes, using "sink" I can solve this trick.

```
sink("mydata.txt", append=T, split=T)
sink(cnv.print(data))
data <- fread("mydata.txt", header=T, sep="\t")
```

The problem is, I had to correct some lines of "mydata.txt" manually (3 lines) that sometimes the seventh column, jumped to a new line.
I would appreciate if someone had a solution for the file does not break the columns.